# Querying the printer status in windows is unreliable?

Tags: windows, printing, activex, status

I am trying to query my local printers printer status to see if a print job I have just sent has been successful or if the printer is in an error state (out of paper for example).

I can successfully query the printer status in windows but the problem is when my printer becomes out of paper it can take windows up to 3 minutes to detect that its out of paper. This does not work well when I'd like to give the user feedback on the status of their printing.

Why does it take Windows so long to update its printer status even when I send a print job. I would have thought that if the job is sent and it's unsuccessful due to an error then the printer would report this error immeidalty. This is a network printer of course.

Other than "its a driver issue" how can I improve the speed of receiving these printer status updates on jobs in the printer queue?

(Oh, and my pritner sometimes also removes jobs from the printer queue when sending them to an erroring printer. This means that I can't see them in windows but they do still print if I resolve the printer error [by putting paper in]. It just all seems very unreliable).

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: This stuff critically depends on the vendor supplied printer driver and monitor.  And yes, it is a sorry lot these days.  Competition in the hardware business doesn't leave much room for decent software engineer wages.  Touch anything printer related only with a 10-foot pole.

Answer (score 0):

Rob, to start with your last question: if your printer can buffer the job, then the job will be out of the queue and into the printer even though it's out of paper. Same result at this end.

I also noticed that my network printer takes a minute or so to show up as online after I switch the printer back on (yes, I was working at a printer/queue/job status monitor today).

It's not something you (or System.Printing) can do anything about.